# HttpClient Default Headers

Tags: java, httpclient

Is there a way to configure default request headers for HttpClient (the newer version)? I've done a lot of searching but I can't find anything on the new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you mean HttpClient 4.0.1 API ([javadocs are here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/httpclient/apidocs/index.html))...

Look at class [HttpOptions](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/httpclient/apidocs/index.html).  It inherits from [HttpMessage](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/httpclient/apidocs/index.html), which has such methods as addHeader(...), setHeader(...), etc.  It also inherits from HttpRequestBase, which seems to indicate that it is a request object in its own right.  It has constructors that will accept a string or a URI.